# Sending device address to ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) in android -bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have button called scan, that scans the available blue-tooth devices and make a list view.
When i press on some device in that device list , 'm calling ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) but how to send the clicked device address to this.'m using below code.In this 'm able to getting name but how to get the address.

```
  ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single list item on click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

              mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked device", 2).show();
              String address = mArrayAdapter.get(position);
              device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

              new ConnectThread(device);
          }
        });
```

ConnectThread code:

```
 private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "device: " + device, 2).show();
        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }
    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
       // manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer for this question. Used below code when item i clicked in list view.

```
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single list item on click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

              mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

              String info = mArrayAdapter.get(position);
              String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
              device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
              new ConnectThread(device);

          }
        });
```